# How to add result of Sql query(via SQL to LINQ) to datagrid in WPF

Tags: wpf

Hi i want to add the result of sql query to datagrid in my WPF application. I use SQL to LINQ to fetch data.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Set the ItemSource property of the DataGrid to the value of the result of that query using C# :

```
dataGrid1.ItemSource = query ;
```

ensure you set the AutoGenerateColumns property into true in XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Comment: what to do in case when i use grid control ,                    <Grid Height="341" Name="grid1" Width="833"  >
       

    </Grid>